# Why does this code log return false?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop

I can't figure out why this snippet logs false. I'm convinced it should log to true. What am I doing wrong?

```js
var hasElb = function(string12b,char12b) {
    var el = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < string12b.length; i++ ) {
        if (string12b[i] === char12b) {
            el += char12b;
        }
    }
    if (el[0] === char12b) {
        console.log(true + " el[0] = " + el[0] + " and char12b = " + char12b);
    }
    else {
        console.log(false + " el[0] = " + el[0] + " and char12b = " + char12b);
    }
};
hasElb([1,3,5,7,9,11],7);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an element to an array, you use `.push()`, not `+=`:

```
    if (string12b[i] === char12b) {
        el.push(char12b);
    }
```

Comment: Ugh. Of course. Thanks! I'm still not sure why the other version doesn't work. The final value of el === 7, making the character in position[0] of var el === 7. This worked when I was just using a string in "string12b". Is it because I'm using an array now? I'm just starting to learn javascript, obviously.

Comment: Nevermind, @Pointy, you actually told me explicitly in your answer it's the array. Thanks!